Обработка переменных шаблонизатора django в коде html
views.py
def index(request):
    pwd = "PASS_WORD"
    html = '<ul>\
        <li>Инженер:<br>\
            <ul>\
                <li><b>USER:</b> deltav</li>\
                <li><b>PASS:</b> {{pwd}}</li>\
            </ul>\
        </li>\
    </ul>'
    data = {'pwd': pwd, 'html':html}
    return render(request, "index.html", context = data)

index.html
{% extends "template.html" %}
{% block title %}Главная{% endblock title %}
{% block content %}
    <hr>
    {% spaceless %}
        {{html|safe}}
    {% endspaceless %}
    <hr>
{% endblock content %}

Подскажите пожалуйста, как заменить переменную {{pwd}} в html коде, хранящимся в переменной html средствами шаблонизатора django? Или правильней эту замену делать в контроллере views?

Правильнее в принципе не пихать html в views, для чего вы это сделали?

Это сделано для примера. Страница html хранится в БД

А для чего вы храните html в БД? И учли вы возможные последствия того, что кто-нибудь нехороший попытается написать туда гадость через админку или что там у вас?

Это закрытая система с инструкциями, которые необходимо обновлять

Ну в общем если вы всем доверяете, то просто используйте Template и render_to_string
